# Show react native debug menu on Xperia M4 Aqua

Tags: android, react-native

normally on Android device I would simply hold the back button to show in app debugging menu,  but I've just got this phone and I have no idea how to.

How many ways are there to show in app debugging menu for react native, and is there any specific way for Sony Xperia M4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using 'adb shell', and run 'input keyevent 82' to show context menu and reload as I wish.